# Chrome user:pass login not working?

Tags: python

I am attempting to use chrome with a user pass proxy this is my code:

```
def getProxy(string_only=True):
    try:
        proxy_manager = ProxyManager("proxies.txt")
        proxy = proxy_manager.random_proxy() 
        if string_only:
            return proxy.proxy_string
        return proxy.get_dict()
    except (OSError, IOError, IndexError) as e: # couldn't load the file / file is empty
        return None
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    proxy = getProxy()
    userpass = proxy[0:proxy.find("@")]
    hostport = proxy[proxy.find("@")+1:]
    if proxy:
        chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=" + hostport)
    driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver1, 1000000)
    if manual == "No":
        driver1.get("http://%s@www.google.com"%userpass)
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: proxy is formatted as user:pass@localhost:8080

Comment: What _exactly_ is the issue with the code you provided?

Comment: @csmckelvey Sorry forgot to mention, I still recieve a login popup

Comment: Btw manual does = no I just cannot show the full code as it's private